# How to fix my Drop Down to make it disable a component according to selection

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular7

I am building an Angular application and using reactive forms. I am currently working with a form that handles multiple inputs and dropdowns, The problem is that i would like to disable the dropdown according to very specific requierments.

I have tried using ngIf directives inside my template however, i couldn't make it work and it seems that the best approach is to do it programmatically.

The problem is split into two:

- 1- There are 2 dropdowns wrapped together and they represent "hours" and "minutes", the point is, if the user selects the maximum hour, the minutes should be disabled (which i have done already) by subcribing to value change.
- 2- I am trying to find a way to do the same thing without repeating the same function i did for the hours.

This is what i have so far (first working solution)

this is in the add-edit-tank

```
 onTimeChange() {
    this.tankForm.get('hours').valueChanges.subscribe(selectedHour => {
      if (selectedHour == '124') {
        this.tankForm.get('minutesCounter').disable();
      } else {
        this.tankForm.get('minutesCounter').enable();
      }
    });
  }
```

And the following is the code in my HTML.

```
 <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <label for="hours" class="label"
                >Select the hours and minutes</label
              >
              <div class="select is-test">
                <select
                  class="form-control"
                  id="hours"
                  formControlName="hours"
                  #hr
                >
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Hours</option>
                  <option
                    value
                    *ngFor="let index of counter(32); let i = index"
                    [value]="i * 4"
                  >
                    {{ i }}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown is-hoverable">
                <div class="select">
                  <select formControlName="minutesCounter" #min>
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Minutes</option>
                    <option
                      *ngFor="let minute of minutesCounter"
                      [value]="minute.id"
                      >{{ minute.minutes }}</option
                    >
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The expected result is the following:

- **When the user selects 0 hours and 0 minutes, i would like to disable the hours drop down and remove (0) from the minute select drop down**.